# Moving my Blogger (custom) domain to a new hosting provider

Tags: wordpress, dns, google-apps, blogger

I'm looking to move my custom domain from blogger to wordpress. I have purchased the domain through google, and it's now a google apps account. What I would like to do it change the site to point to a new host, but I'd like to keep everything else in tact (the current blog will stick around, I'm just looking to point the domain to a new host). I want to keep the google apps going so I can manage the email, etc.

Currently, the domain is through ENOM, and the default hosting information is:

```
@   216.239.32.21   A (Address)
@   216.239.34.21   A (Address)
@   216.239.35.21   A (Address)
@   216.239.36.21   A (Address)
docs   ghs.google.com   CNAME (Alias)
calendar   ghs.google.com   CNAME (Alias)
...(Rest of the google apps here)
```

So, is there a way to point JUST the web hosting to  my new media temple host? So www.mydomain.com gets served from the media temple host?

If I change the DNS settings to "Custom" I lose all of the google stuff, and it says the only way I can set up the MX records and whatnot are by using the default settings.

Has anyone ever done this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose custom DNS, you can setup the DNS to keep working with Google. Some steps here http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=140034 http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=54693

Then point the website (A) records to your new host.

(On a side note, I'm not a fan of Media Temple. I've got a client with a WP site on there and there are better hosts.)

I have quite a few sites hosted with multiple hosts, and email running through Google Apps email, including the client who is on MT.